# How to set up a live test site?

Tags: testing, web, filezilla

This is probably really obvious to most of you but i am new to this.

How do you set up a live test site that does not use the primary domain name? At the moment the primary domain name is being used for a temporary landing page and I want that to be the case until the site goes live. I am using the filezilla.

The advice I had been given was to publish it to a sub folder or the htaccess file on the server so it can be configured to restrict access (e.g. by username and password) but I am not sure how to do that. Can you let me know the steps involved, bearing in mind I do not want a second domain but to test the site on a live server so others can see it but not using the primary domain.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is , as you said, to put the new site into an subfolder or you can create a new subdomain for that site. But if there is no need for that, i would prefer  a simple subfolder in the folder the domain points to.

I think it shouldn't be too tricky to create a subfolder and put the files in it, simple rightklick in filezilla and name it.

For creating an htaccess password protection you need two files. 
One called .htacccess and the other .htpasswd (the point in front of the name is important).

.htacces looks like:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Hallo"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
require valid-user
```

.htpasswd contains in each line one user with encrypted pw:

```
username:1$3OVCsRyzKhk
```

You'll find a lot of examples via google. Just type "htaccess htpasswd", and there will be also some generator which will help you.

To enter your site, just type in browser: example.com/NewSubfolder/

Comment: Sorry to be follish but how do you get the url for the site without using a domain name?

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought you just wanted that example.com doesn't point to that new site. If you want no subdomain or subfolder of example.com, then i don't know what to do. In the way i described, you either have for sub.example.com or example.com/path for your new site and the old one would not be affected. Maybe i understood you wrong...

Comment: By the way, if no domain name, you have to use the ip. or what else is left over?

Answer (score 1):

Really not too much too it -- just stand up a separate website, perhaps using a virtual site on that server or perhaps on a different server entirely. Presuming you are using relative paths like you should be this works just fine.

One other trick would be to set it up in place but use the default document directive to steer people to the placeholder page unless they knew what your home page's direct url is.

Comment: Do I need a second domain to do this? If not, how do you get the url for the site without one?

Comment: Lots of ways to do that. Many folks use a different host -- such as qa.example.com or staging.example.com. Others use a different port. Others use raw IP addresses. And other people actually purchase a second domain. But remember in this context that all you are looking for is a means to tell your web server to serve a different site. Names don't generally matter.